# How to stop log4net from writing to two separate files

Tags: .net, log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm using the below log4net configuration.  I'm trying to write performance logs to a separate file but the output is going to both files.  Even though I'm specifiying:

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("PerformanceMetricsLogger");
```

How do I stop log4net from writing to the default appender in this case?

```
<log4net>
  <!-- Define some output appenders -->
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">    
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="c:\ilap\IlapAdServerLog_%property{log4net:HostName}.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
    <maximumFileSize value="2000KB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="RollingFileAppenderForPerformance" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="c:\ilap\IlapAdServerLog_%property{log4net:HostName}.peformance.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
    <maximumFileSize value="2000KB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default level -->
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  </root>

  <logger name="PerformanceMetricsLogger">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppenderForPerformance" />
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the logger levels below root inherit the appenders from the root logger. This is why your messages are logged twice. To disable inheritance of your logger set its [additivity](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Additivity.html) parameter to false:

```
 <logger additivity="false" name="PerformanceMetricsLogger">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppenderForPerformance" />
  </logger>
```